# Texture Painting draw tool doesn't work, but fill tool does

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm trying to texture paint a character in blender, however I'm running into a problem. I'm able to use the fill tool to color in the mesh, but the draw doesn't do anything.

For example, when I use the fill tool and choose a color like blue, then click the character, it turns blue. But when I select the draw tool and try to color the character, nothing happens. [image]

[image]

Here's a picture of my UV's. I think I got everything for the texture painting to work. Does anybody know why it doesn't?!?

Comment: Hello could you please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I've found the answer. It's because I had a texture for my paint brush. Since there was no texture, nothing happened when I clicked with the brush. I solved this by going to the texture properties tab and deleting the brush